# Using a pen drive + secure certificate instead of sudo passwords

Tags: sudo, hardware-token

Is this recommended and/or possible? I just don't like the idea of anyone beside me being able to see when I type my password.

Comment: It looks like sudo supports PAM, so you should be able to do something like [this](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3029711).

Answer (score 2):

When you talk about a pen drive and certificate based authentication, you probably want two-factor-authentication (2FA). This means that you do not use the pen drive instead of the password but in addition to the password. If I understood your question correctly, you are not doing this for usability but for added security, therefore 2FA is the way to go.

It is possible to configure sudo with 2FA - e.g. there is a [guide for a Yubikey implementation](https://www.maxoberberger.net/blog/2018/12/yubikey.html). This is just an example, as the configuration will depend on the actual hardware you are using. Any [FIDO/U2F device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_2nd_Factor) that's supported by your OS can be used.

For the sake of completeness, you actually can configure sudo to work without a password, just using the pen drive, but I would not recommend this from a security perspective. Both options are shown in chapter 4.a) and 4.b) respectively in this [guide for Fedora](https://www.ha-obsession.net/2017/05/u2f-sudo-fedora-25.html).